# Grid System in LaTeX

Tags: typography, line-spacing, grid-typesetting

I'd like to typeset documents using the '[Grid system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid%5F%28page%5Flayout%29)' of page layout. Good examples are on pages 40-53 of [this document](http://www.vignelli.com/canon.pdf). The [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/textpos.html) package is helpful for this, but two additional features would be useful:

1. Automatic flow of text across (arbitrarily placed) columns / textpos blocks.
2. Vertical line spacing enforced to be an integer multiple of a base line spacing, even when interrupted (for example) by an equation of arbitrary height.

Any ideas as to how either or both of these could be accomplished?

Comment: +1 for the link to The Vignelli Canon -- interesting document.

Comment: Are non-Latex answers (i.e., Context answers) acceptable?

Comment: It looks as though there is no neat solution (to point 2 at least) in LaTeX, so ConTeXt (etc.) answers would also be interesting.

Comment: The link is outdated, could you upload a screenshot to keep the question relevant? Would be great!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your requirement 2 is very difficult in latex (and a frequent topic of discussion when people get together to talk about future versions). As well as the [grid](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grid) package there is the [gridset](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gridset) package. The [grid](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grid) package tries to make all vertical spaces a multiple of the baselineskip (or pairs of pre-/post-spacing that sum to a multiple of baselineskip), and removes vertical glue. The [gridset](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gridset) package tries to "reset" the text back onto the grid after an odd-sized equation or floating figure or table, but it doesn't necessarily do it in the most aesthetic way, and it may take *many* compilation passes before convergence.

For your requirement 1, check out the [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package. It seems to do what you want.

Comment: Aha! flowfram looks like it handles point 1 rather well.

Answer (score 23):

If you would consider using ConTeXt: First, I don't know if I fully understand your question, but re.1 if you mean a DTP like flow of text across chained boxes it's not possible in ConTeXt. However you can take a look at the possibilities offered by [columnsets](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/columns.pdf) and see if they fit your needs. Obviously you can also try using [layers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/layers) to obtain really complicated layouts.

re.2

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]
```

and see options for

```
\setupinterlinspacing
```

in [ConTeXt manual](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-eni.pdf), for more of grid trickery see [Details](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

### Commercial Plug

Just for completeness, there is a commercial TeX-based *data-based publishing* system named [DocScape](http://www.docscape.de) which is very much geared towards this kind of layout. See [a product catalogue](http://www.erco.com/download/data/10_catalogues/10_catalogue/120_en/en_0_catalogue_2012.pdf) (62 MB!) as an example.

In practise, it mostly handles only question 1 (apart from setting `\lineskiplimit` and allowing to grid-aligned table rows), but being made for catalogs and such, it currently doesn't handle maths anyway ;-)

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the author.

Comment: Can you please update the link to the product catalog, it doesn't work anymore. English will be welcome too, your website is only available in German...

Comment: The particular page [wasn't captured](https://web.archive.org/web/20160901000000*/www.erco.com/download/data/10_catalogues/10_catalogue/120_en/en_0_catalogue_2012.pdf) and the other related stuff also seems to be gone. Wasn't able to find any PDF that large on archive.org.

Answer (score 3):

See the grid package http://ctan.org/pkg/grid.