# Problems with pictures in multicol

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, multicol, grid-typesetting

I am writing a short article for a magazin and want to have a two-column text. Since the header is supposed to be centered, I decided to use the multicol-package. This is my header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[latin1, utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Anmerkungen}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleINeeded{%
\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
\linewidth
\else
\Gin@nat@width
\fi
}\makeatother
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

My problem is the following: I want to include pictures in only one column like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Vinland}
\captionof{figure}{\textit{Ein möglicher Verlauf der Reise Leif Erikssons mit einer möglichen geographischen Zuordnung der Entdeckungen (Karte: Finn Bjørklid)}} 
\end{minipage}
\end{center}{}
```

That works and the picture ist shown in the text at the right position, but the space between the description of the picture and the following line of the text does not have the right length. Therefore the lines of the right column do not correspond with the lines of the left column any longer, the text of the whole page ist totally asymmetric and one column has one and a half lines more than the other. I don't know the reason for that problem and couldn't find any help on the internet. I hope someone here can help me!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 6):

The `grid` package works in this case, but apparently it is not very reliable. You have to try to see if it's okay for you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1, utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvips,demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[grid]{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[baseline=14pt,fontsize=11pt,lines=45]{grid}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\blindtext

\begin{gridenv}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Vinland}
\captionof{figure}{\textit{Ein möglicher Verlauf der Reise Leif Erikssons mit einer möglichen geographischen Zuordnung der Entdeckungen (Karte: Finn Bjørklid)}} 
\end{gridenv}

\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: grid layout]

Comment: Grid typesetting in LaTeX is difficult. This is probably the easiest way to do it for now.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a remark: If you include pictures by using a minipage environment instead of a (floating) figure environment, you may have to manually sort out column breaks and page breaks. (On the other hand, figure environments spanning only one column are not possible with the multicol package.)

Your question regarding lines in different columns not corresponding to each other actually is a feature request for grid typesetting. To quote from an answer to a [former question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/grid-system-in-latex): "Your requirement [...] is very difficult in latex (and a frequent topic of discussion when people get together to talk about future versions)."