# How to control spaces between objects?

Tags: spacing, grid-typesetting

I have a problem with controlling spaces between different object and environment. In my MWE you can see I use `quote` and `\footnote` on the one page. Unfortunatelly when I use them lines on adjoining pages (on even and odd pages) don't harmonize (as you can see).
I try to set spaces between text and quotations by using `\vspace`s but it doesn't want to work always. Sometimes it's ok, but sometimes last line goes to the next page. I try to make (I think I try) the space between text and footer more flexible, but it doesn't work as I want.

Do you know what is the best way to control it?
I don't want to use `\raggedbottom`, because I want my columns to be equal.
Thank you for any help.

PS. Do you know if there is any package to show a grid in my document?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
  centering,
  top=12mm,
  headheight=14pt,
  headsep=11pt,
  includeheadfoot,
  papersize={160mm,235mm},
  text={125mm,190.7mm},
]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{14pt} 
\setlength\floatsep{12pt plus 12pt minus 2pt} 

\clubpenalty10000 
\widowpenalty10000

\sloppy 

\setlength{\skip\footins}{11pt plus 11pt minus 4pt}

\usepackage{footmisc} 
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt} 

\frenchspacing

\usepackage{lipsum}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont

\lipsum

\begin{quote}
\small Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some  text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text }

\begin{quote}
\small Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you seem to be asking about on-grid typesetting. If so, the second part of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1418/627) should be relevant.

Comment: @Lev Bishop, yes, I ment grid typesetting. Thanks for your answer. Later I'll check if it works.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to your main question, but as for your PS: getting a baseline grid on the page can be accomplished as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{grid}{gray}{0.8}
\newlength{\topline}
\setlength{\topline}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\topline}{-1in}
\addtolength{\topline}{-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\topskip}
\newcounter{nlines}
\setcounter{nlines}{\textheight / \baselineskip}
\AtBeginDocument{
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \color{grid}
    \multiput(0,\strip@pt\topline)%
    (0,-\strip@pt\baselineskip){\value{nlines}}%
        {\line(1,0){\strip@pt\paperwidth}}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. Your script works great! I still need help with my main problem. If anyone knows what to do it'd be great.

Comment: @kotsport: You should upvote Michel's answer if it is useful to you.

Comment: do you know how to set constant spaces between line in a grid? When I change font size in a document, a grid changes too and I don't want it.

Comment: @kotsport: it uses \baselineskip as line spacing in the grid. Just change `\strip@pt\baselineskip` to read `10` for a skip of 10pt. The number of lines is controlled using the counter nlines, which I set to `\textheight / \baselineskip`, obviously, you could remove `\value{nlines}` (and the definition of the counter itself) and just hard-code some value there.