# Change header if title is first on page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, conditionals

(Not a dupe of [Is something the first item on a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114861/is-something-the-first-item-on-a-page) and another similar question, because these involve preventing rules at the top of a page by putting them in leaders; but leaders require boxes, and I don't want a box, but simply to issue a header command.)

So I often roll my own sectioning commands, and I'm currently typesetting a volume which has frequent, shorter chapters.  As a result, I don't want to start a new page for every chapter, so when I wrote my sectioning command, it simply skips, prints the title, sends the title to the TOC, then skips again to be ready for the text.  Normally, these chapters do *not* begin at the start of a page; so in that case, having the full, normal header is the correct behavior.

Occasionally, however, the chapters *do* begin at the top of a page, and in those circumstances I'd like to have the equivalent of `\thispagestyle{plain}` happen.  I can't simply put that in the chapter definition, because most of the time the chapters don't start at the top of the page.  I only want a `plain` pagestyle when the chapter falls at the top of the page.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyhead{Header}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\def\newchap#1{%
    \vskip 3em plus1em minus0.5em%
    \hbox to\linewidth{\LARGE\hfil#1\hfil}%
    \vskip 3em plus1em minus0.5em%
}%
\begin{document}
\newchap{New Chapter Here}
\end{document}
```

Notice that, although the chapter is the first thing on the page, we end up with the full header.  (As the code directs.)  I'd like to know something I can put in `\newchap` which, when it's at the top of the page, will issue `\thispagestyle{plain}`, or something with equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not thoroughly tested, but should suffice with some tweaking.

The idea is to update `\newchap` to include some code from [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace). This allows you to force a new page based on the amount of space available on the page, and condition accordingly between issuing `\thispagestyle{plain}` and `\thispagestyle{fancy}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr,afterpage}

\newif\iftopchap
\topchaptrue% You'll start with a chapter at the top

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32622/5764
\makeatletter
% \needspace{<len>}{<NOT enough space>}{<enough space>}
\newcommand{\needspace}[3]{\par \penalty-100\begingroup
  \setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \dimen@ii\pagegoal \advance\dimen@ii-\pagetotal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\dimen@ii% execute the following if there IS NOT enough space on page
    \ifdim \dimen@ii>\z@
      \vfil
    \fi
    \break
    #2% <NOT enough space>
  \else% execute the following if there IS enough space on page
    #3% <enough space>
  \fi\endgroup}
\makeatother

\fancyhead{Header}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\newchap}[1]{%
  \par
  \needspace{6em}{% <not enough space>
    \global\topchaptrue
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \afterpage{\global\topchapfalse}%
  }{% <enough space>
    \iftopchap\else\thispagestyle{fancy}\fi
  }%
  \vspace{3em plus 1em minus 0.5em}
  \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\LARGE #1}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{3em plus 1em minus 0.5em}
}%

\begin{document}
\sloppy% Just for this example

\thispagestyle{plain}
\newchap{New chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\newchap{Another chapter}
\lipsum[2-3]

\newchap{Yet another chapter}
\lipsum[3-7]

\newchap{Penultimate chapter}
\lipsum[4-5]

\newchap{Final chapter}
\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

The choice for a required space of `6em` for the heading is based on an estimate of the header size (vertical space included). This may require some adjustment from your end to ensure proper page-breaking.