# Twocolumn document misalignement due to section

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, vertical

I have a `table*` enviroment in a `twocolumn` article. After the table, the text on both sides is misaligned, which is only happening, when immediately after the table a section occurs.

How do I get rid of that and perfect aligned columns?

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Table A}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        A & B \\
        C & D
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\FloatBarrier
\section{Test}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Precisely what do you man that the columns are misaligned?  Is it that the baselines in the two columns don't line up?  That is not because of the table; the same thing would happen if the table weren't there, as long as the first column begins with a section heading.  The heading and the following space don't occupy the same depth as an integral number of text lines.  I think what you are expecting is what is known as "grid typesetting".  That is possible, but most document classes aren't designed that way.

Comment: Ok, thats what i meant @barbara beeton. So you are suggest, to not care about this? Isn't there an option, where i would change the space of the `section` and the empty space below to a multiple integer of a text height?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `scrartcl` document class (I've added the `koma-script` tag since this may be significant, and removed the `tables` tag), but grid typesetting is not the default in (La)TeX.  The question [Spacing of sectioning commands for grid typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23624/579) has a suggestion in one answer regarding an experimental koma package, but it's old, and I know nothing else about it.  If you're determined, there are some possible hacks, but they shouldn't be considered before your document is otherwise final.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by barbara beeton the `\section` title does not take up an integral number of lines.

You can add/subtract space after the title using the `\vspace` macro. Below is an edited version of your MWE where I have used this; I also used `lipsum` because that provides multiple paragraphs.

```
% twocolprob.tex  SE 530027 not grid set

\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{placeins}
\raggedbottom          % need this because of changing vertical spacing(?)
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Table A}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        A & B \\
        C & D
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\FloatBarrier
\section{Test}
%\vspace{-10pt} % moves text up after heading
\vspace{3pt}    % moves text down after heading
%\blindtext[4]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In general the `\vspace` macro length needs to be adjusted according to the particular document style.