# Alignment with Multicols and Polyglossia

Tags: xetex, multicol, polyglossia

I'm working with a two column multicol environment for an English-Yiddish dictionary (using XeLaTeX and Polyglossia).  I have a couple of issues, and I'm putting them all together because I'm not sure whether the solutions are related.

(1) I'd like to align the bottoms of the columns.  I'm aware that this has been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53008/align-baseline-in-multicol), but using the grid package has not helped (perhaps I'm using it wrong).  Note, I'm not worried about individual lines on the left lining up with those on the right, but that the columns look justified vertically as a whole.  It seems to work until I add the line `\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}`.

(2) I'd like each of the entries that spill onto a second line to be indented on the left after the first line as well as on the right.  I can't seem to figure out how to get `\hangindent` to do both left and right.

**EDIT:** I solved this by increasing the entire paragraph `\leftskip` and putting a negative `\hspace` on the first line.  It feels like a bad hack, and I would love a better answer.

(3) Looking at the translation for "be eager to", there seems to be a line break inserted after "בעלן" when the `\hspace` in the definition of `\subentry` is set to 0.3cm or higher, but this problem doesn't occur when `\hspace` is inserting 0.2cm.  What could be causing this?

Code (with a decent number of [repeated] entries to fill a page):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia, multicol}

\setlength{\textwidth}{7.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\RL{\texthebrew{#1}\hfil}}
\newcommand{\hangparagentry}{\hangindent-0.5em \hangafter1 \leftskip 0.3em \parindent -0.5em}
\newcommand{\hangparagsubentry}{\hangindent-0.5em \hangafter1 \leftskip 1.1em \parindent -0.5em}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entry}{ m o m }{\noindent\hangparagentry{\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.5cm}\hfill \h{#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}\par}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\subentry}{ m o m }{\noindent\hangparagsubentry{\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3cm}\hfill \h{#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}\par}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\flushright

\begin{multicols}{2}

\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{E}{}
\subentry{(letter)}{דער ע, ־ען}
\subentry{(mus.)}{דער מי, ־ען}
\subentry{E flat}{מי בעמאָל}
\subentry{E sharp}{מי דיעז}
\entry{eager}[[LÓET/LÓER]]{להוט (אױף/צו); נײַגעריק}
\subentry{be eager to}[[BALN] [KhÉYShEK] [LÓET/LÓER]]{זײַן אַ בעלן צו; האָבן חשק צו; זײַן נײַגעריק ‹להוט› צו; זײ֜ער ‹שטאַרק› װעלן}
\subentry{be eager to please}{שטאַרק באַמיִען זיך צו געפֿעלן}
\entry{ear}{}
\subentry{(anat.)}{דער/דאָס אױער, ־ן}
\subentry{(hearing)}{דאָס געהער}
\subentry{(of corn)}{די פּשעניטשקע, ־ס; די זאַנג ‹דאָס זאַנגל› קוקורוזע; דער קאַטשן, קאַטשענעס}
\subentry{be all ears}{אױפֿשטעלן די אױערן; אָנשטעלן מױל און אױערן}
\subentry{up to one's ears in}{איבערן קאָפּ מיט; ביז איבער די אױערן מיט}
\subentry{by ear (mus.)}{לױטן געהער; נאָכן געהער נאָך}
\subentry{have a good ear}{האָבן אַ גוט אױער; האָבן אַ גוט געהער; האָבן אַן אױער פֿאַר מוזיק}
\subentry{have an ear to the ground}[[DÉYFEK]]{װיסן װאָס סע טוט זיך; האַלטן אַ פֿינגער אױפֿן דפֿק}
\subentry{have sb.'s ear}{האָבן אַ טיר צו}
\subentry{It went in one ear and out the other}[[BEKhÉYREM]]{ס׳איז מיר אין אײן אױער אַרײַן און פֿון צװײטן אַרױס; פֿרעג מיך בחרם װאָס ער האָט געזאָגט}
\subentry{to my ear}[[KhUSh]]{לױט מײַן חוש}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```