# Align the baselines of two columns of text

Tags: multicol, grid-typesetting

I'm trying to get the baselines of the two adjacent columns here below to be properly aligned. The package `grid` cannot handle the floats as I want, so I've tried with `gridset`. It looks like it can do the job but I can't get it to work...

This is the page after it's been typeset using `gridset`:
[image]

You can see the last line of the second column is higher than the first.

[I Know](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/grid-system-in-latex) that setting up a grid system in LaTeX isn't the easiest job but I hope there's a fix for my issue. Any solution is welcome, I'm not restricted to use `gridset`.

---

(Not so M)WE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[top=.6667in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
  \setlength{\droptitle}{-31.5pt}% aligns the top of the title with the top of the right column
  \preauthor{}
  \author{}
  \postauthor{}
  \predate{}
  \date{}
  \postdate{}
  \pretitle{\noindent\bfseries\fontsize{40pt}{0pt}\selectfont}% the font size can be modified if needed
  \title{Title}
  \posttitle{}
\usepackage{multicol}
  \setlength{\columnsep}{.25in}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\usepackage{gridset}
\usepackage{lettrine}
  \renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\upshape}
  \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color[gray]{0.5}}
  \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\usepackage[osfI,sups]{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\frenchspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{thepicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\savepos{pos1}
%\theposinfo{pos1}% in my case y=44087932; my picture is 691x137
%\thegridinfo{pos1}
\edef\gridbase{44087932}
\maketitle
\vskipnextgrid
\lettrine{L}{orem} \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is almost a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53008/align-baseline-in-multicol, but I didn't find an answer there.

Comment: There is also `grid-system`. I thought there was a new package using the l3* stuff but I can't seem to find it so may be imagining it.

Comment: Here's the question: where exactly do you want LaTeX to add the vertical space required to get the columns to align? You have basically redefined every element used on that page in a way that removes the stretchy glue which usually gets used as filler. There is no glue around the title (or author or date) and no glue at paragraph breaks. And there is none, really, any place else. If the first column did not include a problematic font size, that would be fine. But 40pt is not, it seems getting you an exact multiple of a regular line. So things cannot possibly be aligned at both top and base.

Comment: Also, are you sure that combining `gridset` and `multicols` is wise?

Comment: @cfr The space should go between the title and the beginning of the text. I don't know if it's wise to combine these two packages, but afaik my only alternative is to use ConTeXt and I don't know it. I took out the part redefining the `\parskip` and tried `\posttitle{\vspace{0pt plus \baselineskip}}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ideally, if I knew all the vertical spaces between the title and the figure and between the title and the text I could choose a font size such that the sum is a multiple of the `\baselineskip` (but then I don't know how the font size relates to the text height). I tried to make a complicate thing just for exercise... But I came to like the layout and I'd like to make something out of it, that's why I'm asking for help here. So, thanks :-)

Comment: Why can't you use `multicols` without `gridset`?

Comment: @cfr Because the baselines are not aligned with `multicols` alone.

Comment: @cfr Tried without `gridset` and with `\posttitle{\vspace{0pt plus 13.6pt}}` (13.6pt being my `\baselineskip`) and it worked! Does it depend on `\flushcolumns` now being able to work more freely thanks to the glue? I was a bit careless in effect in redefining all the pre- and post-stuff. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I am not sure but I think so. I think when you redefine everything without any glue, there's nothing for `\flushcolumns` to work with i.e. there's nothing it can do when they aren't flush. So you are asking it to line stuff up but then specifying everything precisely so that it is impossible to do that.

Comment: I was too hurry to celebrate... as soon as I replaced the dummy picture with the actual one, different in size, columns were all over the place again. Same code. Jeeeez...

Comment: @cfr do you know how to put a glue between the picture and the beginning of the text? A `\vspace` between `\end{figure}` and `\begin{multicols}{2}` makes nothing.

Comment: Try `\vspace*`?

Comment: `\vspace*{0pt plus 13.6pt}` brings the text down by well over the 13.6pt I asked. It works like a switch, 0pt plus 13.6pt adds the same space as 0pt plus 1pt. Thanks anyway

Comment: `\vskip`? But I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: Already tried, it gives an error.

Comment: What you're trying to do is done in `rvdtx`, which uses `grid`.  You won't want to use `rvdtx`, but you can see what trick they're using to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really understand it... Is it the definition of the environment `decl`? I wouldn't know how to use it, however. Just add it in the preamble and put my text inside it?