# Row misaligned when using \dfrac

Tags: multicol, fractions

I can't understand why it's misaligned, what am i doing wrong?
It can be corrected if I use \frac, but it's not what I need

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=4cm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}



\title{E20}
\author{Ing. Luque }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Enunciado}
\LARGE
Sobre una playa en línea recta se consideran los puntos $A$ y $B$. Un navegante desde su embarcación observa dichos puntos y para ello abarca un ángulo de \ang{60}. Si la embarcación equidista de los puntos $A$ y $B$ y la distancia entre dichos puntos es de \SI{10}{\km}, halle la distancia de la embarcación a la playa.\\

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[align=parleft, leftmargin=*, labelsep=.7em, itemsep=2pt]
    \item[A)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\km}
    \item[D)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{5\sqrt{3}}{\km}
    \item[B)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\km}\\
    \item[C)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{5\sqrt{5}}{\km}
    \item[E)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{3\sqrt{3}}{\km}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The content is aligned at the very top, so C) is placed correctly in the sense that the horizontal bars of the square roots, which are the highest part, are aligned. Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53008/237192

Answer (score 7):

As Οὖτις noted in a comment, the alignment is at the top, not the baseline.

You can get the labels to align (at their baseline) by manually adding a `\vphantom` of a `\dfrac` to item "C":

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=4cm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}



\title{E20}
\author{Ing. Luque }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Enunciado}
\LARGE
Sobre una playa en línea recta se consideran los puntos $A$ y $B$. Un navegante desde su embarcación observa dichos puntos y para ello abarca un ángulo de \ang{60}. Si la embarcación equidista de los puntos $A$ y $B$ y la distancia entre dichos puntos es de \SI{10}{\km}, halle la distancia de la embarcación a la playa.\\

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[align=parleft, leftmargin=*, labelsep=.7em, itemsep=2pt]
    \item[A)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\km}
    \item[D)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{5\sqrt{3}}{\km}
    \item[B)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\km}\\
    \item[C)] $\vphantom{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}$\qty[parse-numbers=false]{5\sqrt{5}}{\km}
    \item[E)] \qty[parse-numbers=false]{3\sqrt{3}}{\km}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `tasks` package for horizontal enumerating. Then you can place the items in their natural order and labeling is automatic.

[image]

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=4cm}

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{E20}
\author{Ing. Luque }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Enunciado}
\LARGE
Sobre una playa en línea recta se consideran los puntos $A$ y $B$. Un navegante desde su embarcación observa dichos puntos y para ello abarca un ángulo de \ang{60}. Si la embarcación equidista de los puntos $A$ y $B$ y la distancia entre dichos puntos es de \SI{10}{\km}, halle la distancia de la embarcación a la playa.\\

\begin{tasks}[label=\Alph*), label-offset=.7em](3)
    \task \qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\km}
    \task \qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\km}
    \task \qty[parse-numbers=false]{5\sqrt{5}}{\km}
    \task \qty[parse-numbers=false]{5\sqrt{3}}{\km}
    \task[]
    \task \qty[parse-numbers=false]{3\sqrt{3}}{\km}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```