# Grid typesetting with LaTeX3

Tags: latex3, grid-typesetting

[Grid typesetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_%28page_layout%29) is something that is rather hard to achieve with LaTeX and as this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/grid-system-in-latex) states there are currently two packages, e.g. `grid` and `gridset`, that can help to use grids. Unfortunately none of these packages seem to work flawlessly, `gridset` takes many compilations and `grid` has some limitations, according to the manual e.g. footnotes are not placed correctly.

Since the mentioned question already is some years old and I have read that LaTeX3 may make it easier to achieve grid typesetting, I wanted to know if there have been any improvements or new devlopements. I have found the [`xo-grid`](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/xpackages/xor/xo-grid.dtx) package on the LaTeX3 project page and was willing to give a try, but I couldn't really get it work. Is it already possible to work with `xo-grid` or is not yet ready for use? Or is there another package that I've overlooked?

Comment: Did you see the demos in [`xo-pfloat`](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/xpackages/xor/xo-pfloat.tex)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the present time, `xor` is usable for testing but certainly not ready for more general use. The `xo-grid` code is part of the larger rewrite of the output routine, so the same comment applies.

Getting to grips with `xor` is one of the biggest challenges facing the LaTeX3 Project: the code is complex and has evolved over many years. As such, there is currently no good estimate of when it will be production ready. It's also worth noting that the code will almost certainly break any LaTeX2e package that relies on the LaTeX2e output routine.

What would of course be useful (in addition to offers of help with the code) is to know what you tried and what did not work. This may well be more of a discussion than a strict Q&A issue, so might be best raised on the LaTeX-L list.

Comment: I probably should get on with this :-)

Comment: Is it not possible while `xor` is experimental to save the old output routine and call `xor` explicitly and then handover back to the old output routine. This would also be good for comparisons. Pretty very much like David did in afterpage pkg.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides The problem there is for example that floats are handled entirely differently by the two mechanisms: what then happens to a float if given after a switch of mechanism? More generally, `xor` does work, its just that it needs a proper revision to deal with all of the edge case comments and to get the interfaces, _etc._, correct and stable. You can use it now, but any use at all means documents might have to be changed in the future.

Comment: @JosephWright is your answer (and comment) still accurate at this time? That is, still no good estimate on a production-ready ETA?

Comment: @PaulGessler Things haven't changed here: when they do I'm sure I or someone else will update several questions on it!

Comment: @JosephWright any chance that much progress has been made since 2014? I'd love to be able to use a good grid system.

Comment: @JosephWright Any new updates? Is `xor` still an ongoing project? Are there still plans for a new output routine supporting grid typesetting?