# What exactly is latex3/xor?

Tags: latex3

The LaTeX3 source contains a folder [`xor`](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/tree/master/xpackages/xor) which contains, among other things, `xo-grid`, which is supposed to provide LaTeX3 with grid support. To quote [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104035/19809),

> Getting to grips with `xor` is one of the biggest challenges facing the LaTeX3 Project: the code is complex and has evolved over many years. As such, there is currently no good estimate of when it will be production ready. It's also worth noting that the code will almost certainly break any LaTeX2e package that relies on the LaTeX2e output routine.

However, I was unable to find good documentation about *what* exactly `xor`*is*. I suspect that the `or` might stand for "output routine", but that does not help much. **What exactly is `xor`?**

Comment: You should join the L3 - Team to get more information ;-) As far as I understand it, the `xor` implementation is not meant for production code so far (i.e. usage in documents)

Comment: I don't think I have much to offer them in terms of TeX knowledge. ;-)

Comment: See this for `or` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/an-explanation-of-latexs-output-routine and `x` is the typical way to mention a difference or a new feature such as package names `graphicx,xparse,xstring` and so on.

Comment: Frank wrote about the original implementation of `xor` in his 2000 paper: http://latex-project.org/papers/xo-pfloat.pdf . I believe the code has changed substantially since then (updated for expl3), but otherwise the ideas are still relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, `xor` does not go to CTAN as it is *far too experimental* for general use. As such, beyond the team and highly interested developers there is not an 'audience' for the code and as such not a need to provide detailed documentation.

As the name indicates, `xor` is an *eXperimental Output Routine* for LaTeX (LaTeX3). It is a completely different implementation to the LaTeX2e OR, and importantly handles floats in an entirely different way. The design brief for `xor` is that it should allow fine control of float placement in multiple columns, grid typesetting, clear tracing information, *etc.* To do that, it breaks essentially any LaTeX2e code related to output!

At present, `xor` does work in the sense one can load it and produce a document. However, there are lots of parts of the code that need revision: it's been around in some form since the late 1990s at least. Parts of it need logic revision, parts need 'good practice' revision, parts need documentation, ...

Comment: If this `x` naming scheme is all about being experimental, is `latex` just one big and very late experiment? :-)

Comment: So if I add `xor` to my TeX library, a very minimal LaTeX2e document loading it would work?

Comment: @Gaussler As you'll see in the demo files that are part of `xor`, it will work with a 'vanilla' document.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :-). And `xo-grid`? Has it become more usable since this question was asked? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104035/19809