# How to align lines on facing pages?

Tags: grid-typesetting

Here is my working example. When I add pictures and mathematical formulas, everything looks much worse. The more complicated is content, the less aligned are lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\lipsum{1-11}

\section{Two}
\lipsum{1-11}

\section{Three}
\lipsum{1-11}

\end{document}
```

Here is a printscreen from pdf viewer, I added few horizontal lines to show the problem. Corresponding baselines are not on the same height, are too high or too low

[image]
I also wish to know how set:

- height of a text line in paragraph (is it fontsize?)
- height of space between text lines in paragraph (`\baselineskip` - fontsize?)
- height of space before and after a paragraph
- height of a text line in section/chapter/part name
- height of space between text lines in section/chapter/part name
- height of space before and after a section/chapter/part name
- height of space before and after an environment (equation, figure, itemize)

I know how to add `\vspace{value}`, but I don't know where, I don't know how to overwrite defaults. I prefer to define those all values in one place (at the beginning of document) and use them by own environments/commands (`\mysection{}`) or by standard environments/commands (`\section{}`). Can someone show me how to do it

Can you help me? And sorry for my bad English

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Grid-typesetting is very difficult in latex. Check the [**`grid`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/grid) and [**`gridset`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/gridset) packages. See also [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1418) very similar question.

Comment: My understanding is that ConTeXt does grid typesetting the best of all *TeX options.  All the LaTeX packages suffer from various limitations, unfortunately (maybe the ConTeXt ones do as well).

Comment: Due to the stretch component in TeX's approach, there is not a simple fixed value for these items. Also note that this depends on things like the document class you are using.