# How to use custom command output as lenght?

Tags: macros, grid-typesetting

In order to convince TeX to keep the grid I tried to program a command, that takes a font size switch as parameter and calculates the reminder of the division of the corresponding baseline skip and the `\onelineskip` (the baseline skip of the default size). The commands output should then  be use to set some lengths.

Basically, what I want to do, is passing the output of a custom command directly to `\setlength`.

But I ran into some problems, as if I do something like this:

```
\setlength{\trueGridDiv}{\trueGrid{\secheadstyle}}
```

where `\trueGird` is my custom command putting out a length, I get:

```
Missing number, treated as zero
```

I guess this hangs together with the way TeX is expanding, and I'm wondering, if the approach of using a commands output within `\setlength` is possible at all, and if it is, how?

A workaround could be to set a custom length within the command and use that in `\setlength`:

```
\trueGrid{\secheadstyle} % put the result of it calculations into the length `trueGridOutput`
\setbeforesecskip{-2\onelineskip + \trueGridOutput}
```

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fp, calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stripPT[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother

\newlength{\trueGridH}
\newlength{\trueGridDiv}
\newlength{\test}

\newcommand{\trueGrid}[2][\onelineskip]{%
% Get baselineskip of the given font size.
\settoheight{\trueGridH}{#2 \raisebox{0pt}[\baselineskip][0pt]{}}%
%
% Set the baselineskip. Default is \onelineskip.
\setlength{\trueGridDiv}{#1}%
%
% We do not have modulo function, so we calculate the
% reminder of the devision the given (#2) hight and 
% the default line hight.
\FPdiv\result{\stripPT{\trueGridH}}{\stripPT{\trueGridDiv}}%
\FPtrunc\trunced{\result{}}{0}%
\FPsub\remainder{\result{}}{\trunced{}}%
\FPmul\remainder{\remainder{}}{\stripPT{\trueGridDiv}}%
%
\remainder pt%
}
\newlength{\secheadGrid}
\setlength{\secheadGrid}{\trueGrid{\secheadstyle}}
\setbeforesecskip{-2\onelineskip + \trueGrid{\secheadstyle}}

\begin{document}
\trueGrid{\secheadstyle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it should be expandable to be used within `\setlength` and your macro contains assignments. But do you really need to create your own version instead of simply using one of the existing packages?

Comment: @TeXnician I didn't find a package which helped me in a simple way to hold the grid. But I am grateful for any hint. But I would like to know how to do something like this the right way nevertheless.

Comment: Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/grid (there are some other packages around as well as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/grid-system-in-latex). I must confess that in comparison with ConTeXt grid typesetting in LaTeX is a bit tedious.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks, I will have a look. Switching to ConTeXt is not an option here. But I like to control where the extra space are put, so it is not such a big effort to do it manually. The thing is, that I am too lazy to do the math again every time I use a different font size.

Comment: Unlike TikZ, which runs everything through `\pgfmathparse`, LaTeX command do not evaluate math expression.  You need `\dimexpr` (or `\numexpr`) for that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the hint to `\dimexpr` etc. But I am not sure to which part you a referring: I use `fp` for the calculation in `\setbeforesecskip`. But this is not the part which troubles me.